# deSolve & loop to solve a second order differential equation in R?

Tags: r, loops, differential-equations, desolve

Hello dear community,

I am trying to solve a second order differential equation for quite some time now. The equation reads:

∂P/∂t = D * ∂^2P/∂x^2

I should run it for several P's; P1= df$col1, P2=df$col2, P3=df$col3 of a data frame and D would be df$col4 and x would be df$col5

I am trying to use "deSolve" for this, but at the moment I don't have much success. I would appreciate your input on how to solve a second order differential equation with R.

Comment: It is a partial differential equation that is first order in the time direction that you integrate along (parabolic PDE, heat equation). You seem to apply the method of lines. The data frame gives initial conditions (t=0) for several instances of this task? What are the boundary conditions, constant on the first and last x or some symmetry or something different?

Comment: I'm not sure what your comment says, it is more obfuscating than clarifying. I'd assume that you have a PDE `P_t(x,t) = D(x)·P_xx(x,t)` with `0 <= x <= L`, `P(x,0)` and `D(x)` given as a function table for a discretization of `x in [0,L]` in the columns of your data frame. You then need some conditions for `P(0,t)` and `P(L,t)` to get a completely defined problem. (If `D(x)` is overall negative, the exact and thus also numerical solution will quickly deteriorate, become very ragged in x direction.)

Comment: My comment was too long - therefore please have a look below and sorry for the confusion

Comment: A second order ODE (the van der Pol equation) with deSolve can be found in the following paper https://doi.org/10.32614/RJ-2010-013

Comment: Thanks @tpetzoldt for your input. The reading was very constructive and it gave me some insights that perhaps my approach is not totally incorrect >.> Still since I am using a special case of the convection–diffusion equation I am still seeking for the correct method.

Comment: You may have a look at http://desolve.r-forge.r-project.org and especially in the tutorial http://desolve.r-forge.r-project.org/user2014/tutorial.pdf

Comment: @tpetzoldt, wow that is fantastic! I think I figured already out thanks to your input and this material!! :D thank you so much! 
Ps: I also did a little work around using Eularian method and well without deSolve which is a wonderful package, congrats!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me try again. The boundary conditions - initial conditions for variable P would be; P1(t=0)= 0.4; P2(t=0)= 4.6; P3(t=0) = 0.37. I would like to think just in a code for the first P1 and then I could apply the same for the following columns of my data.frame.

Using deSolve this is what I got so far:
(P1=P)

```
state <- c(P=0.4)
t <- seq(0,100, by=0.1)
J <- function (t, P, parameters) {
  deltax     <- c (1, rep(1, numboxes - 1)) ##doing a vector
  Fluxx       <- -D * diff (c(0,P,0) /deltax #First derivative
 dP    <- diff(Fluxx)/deltax # second derivative
  list(dP,Fluxx)
}
```

**It would also be possible to solve the equation by applying an Eularian method and compute the change in concentration plus the divergence through time.